# Create three arrays from pandas series

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

For example, I have pandas data series like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'ololo'] * 4,
                                'B': np.random.randn(12),
                                'C': np.random.randint(0, 2, 12)})

ga = df.groupby(['A'])['C'].value_counts()

print ga
A       
bar    1    3
       0    1
foo    0    3
       1    1
ololo  0    4
```

I want to create three arrays, like this:

First array

```
bar, foo, ololo
```

Second array (number of '1')

```
2 3 1
```

Third array (number of '0')

```
2 1 3
```

What's a simplest way to do this?

Comment: you should create a code snippet that produces your sample input so others can play around with it easily.

Comment: You have to iterate through your data series, I don't think there is much options here.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the contents of the second and third array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'ololo'] * 4,
    'B': np.random.randn(12),
    'C': np.random.randint(0, 2, 12)
})

counts = df.groupby('A')['C'].value_counts()
```

Gives (for `counts`):

```
A       
bar    1    4
foo    1    4
ololo  0    3
       1    1
dtype: int64
```

So, effectively we want to unstack and transpose so that 0/1 are the index, which we do by:

```
reshaped = counts.unstack().T.reindex([0, 1]).fillna(0)
```

[DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) points out it's possible to avoid `.reindex` by doing the following:

```
reshaped = counts.unstack().T.loc[[0, 1]].fillna(0)
```

Which gives:

```
A  bar  foo  ololo
0    0    0      3
1    4    4      1
```

We force a `.reindex` to ensure it always contains 0/1 (in cases where the randomness means that nothing turns up for 0/1) and force all columns values to be 0 (`.fillna(0)`) where that's the case. You can then get your arrays by doing the following:

```
arrays = reshaped.columns.values, reshaped.loc[1].values, reshaped.loc[0].values
```

Which gives you:

```
(array(['bar', 'foo', 'ololo'], dtype=object),
 array([ 4.,  4.,  1.]),
 array([ 0.,  0.,  3.]))
```